# Problems Implementing PHP-Markdown

Tags: php, markdown, require-once, php-include

I'm experimenting with Michel Fortin's PHP-Markdown library and am having some trouble getting it to work on my server.

I've uploaded the parser library files to my server in a /subfolder. My testmd.php file is one folder up. Currently, I'm using the code below to require_once the files, but my single test line of markdown (a link) is not getting parsed. Is there something else I need to do or include to get the PHP-markdown library working for an example like this?

**testmd.php**

```
<?php
require_once ('subfolder/Markdown.inc.php');
require_once ('subfolder/includetest.php');
?>
<html>
    <body>

<?php
use \Michelf\Markdown;
$html = Markdown::defaultTransform('[Test](www.google.com)');
?>

    </body>
</html>
```

In the code above, includetest.php is just a test include file to be sure I haven't made a mistake there. The file is included in the output, but the MD link is not. No errors appear, so the output looks like:

**output**

```
This is text from the includetest.php file.
```

Since I'm new to PHP, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You’re just embedding the library files, without actually _calling_ it – you need something like `Markdown::defaultTransform('your text here')` …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only loading the parser, but you aren't doing anything with it. You need a line like

```
$my_html = Markdown::defaultTransform($my_text);
```

...to convert markdown to HTML. Like this:

```
<?php
require_once ('subfolder/MarkdownExtra.inc.php');
require_once ('subfolder/includetest.php');
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php Markdown::defaultTransform("[Test](www.google.com)"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I haven't used this before. I'm just going by the docs that I can find.

Comment: I've added PHP to call the parser, but still no luck - it's in the edit above.

Comment: You're just storing the result in $html. You need to output it. Try adding the line `echo $html;` or just echo the call itself.

Comment: thanks for your persistence! It's parsing properly, and now I'm a little less ignorant with PHP.

Comment: There's a learning curve, but the documentation at php.net is excellent. PHP is a fun language.